# Should HBase be installed on the client side? Is sqoop an API? Is Drill an API?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, sqoop, apache-spark

I have done some research about Hadoop, an I still need to know the answer to the following questions:

1. I think HBase is not a core component of Hadoop, hence as a client, what should I do?
2. Is Sqoop an API? If yes, is it implemented in JAVA? Should we install it in the client side?
3. Is Drill also an API? If yes, is it implemented in JAVA? Should we install it in the client side?
4. Is Spark a high-level language? Should we install it in the client side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I think HBase is not a core component of Hadoop, hence as a client, what should I do?

Hbase is not a core component of Hadoop. To use it, you need to install HBase on top of your hadoop cluster. It is dependent on HDFS/Zookeeper. It is not dependent on MapReduce Services.

To use it from the client side, it depends on your use case. You have a Java API/ Rest API or shell access. For shell access you need to have the HBase library on local machine.

### Is Sqoop an API? If yes, is it implemented in JAVA? Should we install it in the client side

Sqoop is an API/tool implemented in java. You will have to install it on the client side.

### Is Drill also an API? If yes, is it implemented in JAVA? Should we install it in the client side?

Drill is not just an API. It is more like a package which has to be installed on the nodes. It provides API based access so client side installation may not be required.

### Is Spark a high-level language? Should we install it in the client side?

Spark is not a high level language and again depends on where the client is. A web application can use Spark API whereas through Shell you would need client library.

Comment: sorry but im new to here, i will mark it as helpful. Thank you. @Venkat